# Is this RAM M393B2G70EB0-CMA compatible with SAMSUNG M393B1G70QH0-CMA already installed on IBM X3650 M4 server?

Tags: memory, hardware

I have a server (IBM X3650 M4 E5-2650 v2) with 16GB RAM (8GBx2) using this RAM part code: (SAMSUNG M393B1G70QH0-CMA) and i want to extend it.

However, is it possible to add different size of new RAM and that would not affect the server?

the suggested items is this (SAMSUNG M393B2G70EB0-CMA) the main specifications are same (speed,voltage) but i'm afraid that there's anything else i should cover while upgrading my RAM capacity.

Comment: How about contacting the vendor and asking them for the recommended RAM upgrade kit? Then you will *know* that it'll work, and if for some obscure reason it doesn't, at least you'll know who to call.

Comment: I tried to, but there's no answer.

Comment: You posted the same part number for both the current and new memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, mismatched memory size does not matter, although you will not be able to run your memory in a multi-channel configuration at a slight performance cost.

Both of these DIMMs are DDR3, 1.35v, 1866MHz, ECC registered and compatible with the x3650 M4.

I cannot guarantee you that they will both work in the x3650 M4 in tandem, but if memory mirroring and sparing is disabled on the server prior to installation of the new memory it should not be an issue.

IBM does not recommend less than 4 DIMMs per CPU for performance reasons. Mismatched DIMMs will also affect performance. Given that it would only be slightly more expensive to get two of the current Samsung 8GB DIMMs versus one of the 16GB DIMMs (used component pricing on ebay.com used for reference), I think that is the ideal solution.